# Exclude factor loadings from ID variable in order to create latent concept

Tags: r

I conducted a factor analysis and wanted to create the latent concept (postmaterialism and materialism) with the correlated variables (see output fa). Later on I want to merge this data set I used for the fa with another data set, hence I kept the ID variable in order to use it later as key variable. Now my problem is that I need to exclude the factor loadings from the ID variable because otherwise it'll contort the score of the latent concept of each individual. I tried different commands like:
`!("ID"), with = FALSE`, `- ("ID"), with = FALSE`, `setdiff(names(expl_fa2),("ID")), with = FALSE`
but nothing worked.

This is my code for the latent variables:

`data_fa_1 <- data_fa_1 %>% mutate(postmat = expl_fa2$score[,1], mat = expl_fa2$scores[,2])`

And this is the output from the factor analysis:

```
Standardized loadings (pattern matrix) based upon correlation matrix
                         MR1   MR2    h2   u2 com
import_of_new_ideas     0.48  0.06 0.233 0.77 1.0
import_of_safety        0.06  0.61 0.375 0.63 1.0
import_of_trying_things 0.66  0.03 0.435 0.57 1.0
import_of_obedience     0.01  0.49 0.240 0.76 1.0
import_of_modesty       0.01  0.44 0.197 0.80 1.0
import_of_good_time     0.62  0.01 0.382 0.62 1.0
import_of_freedom       0.43  0.16 0.208 0.79 1.3
import_of_strong_gov    0.15  0.57 0.350 0.65 1.1
import_of_adventures    0.64 -0.15 0.427 0.57 1.1
import_of_well_behav    0.03  0.64 0.412 0.59 1.0
import_of_traditions    0.03  0.50 0.253 0.75 1.0
import_of_fun           0.67  0.03 0.449 0.55 1.0
ID                      0.07  0.04 0.007 0.99 1.7
```

Can anyone help me with the command I need to use in order to exclude the factor loadings from the ID variable (see output fa) from the creation of the latent variables "postmat" and "mat"?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is really your question, but assuming you just want to remove the first column from a `data.table`, here is an example `data.table` and 3 ways how you could exclude the ID column for that example:

```
DT <- data.table(
  ID=LETTERS[1:10], 
  matrix(rnorm(50), nrow=10, dimnames = list(NULL, paste0("col", 1:5)))
)

DT[,- 1]
DT[, -"ID"]
DT[, setdiff(colnames(DT), "ID"), with=FALSE]
```